# Scala Parsing a really long string as date

Tags: java, scala, date, parsing

I have the following string as part of a CSV file

```
2014-01-30 12:15:00.3 1:0
```

What is the date pattern that can handle this format if any exist? 
I used the following along with other variations

```
val inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+'Z'")
```

But all fail with:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date

Comment: Is `1:0` the [offset from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (so it's equivalent to `+01:00`)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that `1:0` is the [offset from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (in this case, equivalent to `+01:00`).

In `SimpleDateFormat` API, there's no way to recognize this format, as it accepts only offsets in the format `HH:MM` (2 digits for both hours and minutes). Probably you'll have to parse it separately and add the offset manually.

I could find a solution, but it works only for Java 8's [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

*For **Java <= 7**, there's the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), but I'm not sure how well it works with Scala.*

I use a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and a map with custom values for the offset: when the minutes and seconds are zero, I use the values in the format `H:M` (like `1:0`), and for other values I use the normal offsets (like `+01:30`). *You can change this to whatever formats your application receives.*

```
import java.time._
import java.time.format._
import java.time.temporal._

import collection.JavaConversions._
import collection.mutable._

val input = "2014-01-30 12:15:00.3 1:0";
// build a map with custom offset values
// +01:00 becomes 1:0
// when minutes and seconds are not zero, use the default values (like +01:01, +01:30, etc)
var map: java.util.Map[java.lang.Long, String] = HashMap[java.lang.Long, String]()
var i = ZoneOffset.MIN.getTotalSeconds()
while (i <= ZoneOffset.MAX.getTotalSeconds()) {
  var seconds = i
  var hours = seconds / 3600
  seconds -= (hours * 3600)
  var minutes = seconds / 60
  seconds -= (minutes * 60)
  if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0) {
    // minutes and seconds are zero, +01:00 becomes 1:0 
    map.put(i, Integer.toString(hours).concat(":0"))
  } else {
    // minutes and seconds are not zero, use the default values (like +01:01, +01:30, etc)
    var id: String = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(i).getId()
    map.put(i, id)
  }
  i += 1
}
val parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  // date and time
  .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S ")
  // offset, with custom values
  .appendText(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, map)
  // create formatter
  .toFormatter()
// parse the input
val odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(input, parser)
// convert to java.util.Date
var date = new java.util.Date(odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli())
// another way of doing it
date = java.util.Date.from(odt.toInstant())
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the `1:0` supposed to be for at the end?  This is working for me:

```
val input = "2014-01-30 12:15:00.3 1:0"
val inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

val output = inputFormat.parse(input)
println(output) // Thu Jan 30 12:15:00 EST 2014
```

If you had the `Z` in your format because you wanted UTC, then do this:

```
val input = "2014-01-30 12:15:00.3 1:0"
val inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")) // Add this line to set the timezone

val output = inputFormat.parse(input)
println(output) // Thu Jan 30 07:15:00 EST 2014
```